# Inserting into multiple tables ASP.NET & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to execute sql transaction (inserting data to multiple tables if all data is not committed then rollback ) using ASP.NET & c#? The simplest way and the closest way to `sqlCommand` , please !

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you show the way you try? Or didn't you try anything yet?

Comment: I don't know how to do such thing

Comment: which type of sql are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to @Luftwaffe answer:

```
using(TransactionScope tscope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring)
    {
        conn.Open();

        ... Call the necessary stored proc here

        tscope.Complete();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this code :

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your ConnectionString"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Category values(@name);insert into Packages(name,CatId) values(@pname,@catId)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "12");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", "12");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catId", "1");
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the simple way use a `Stored Procedure` for updating all the data in database at once. You can handle the errors in stored proc itself and roll back the transaction there itself.
But if you wish to execute multiple queries from C# onto the SQL Server and want to keep all of them in a single transaction you can use the `TransactionScope Class` provided by .NET.
Here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for that.
Hope it helps.